# Hints on solving $\sum_{i=1}^n i \cdot 2^{i-1}$

Tags: summation

I need hints on solving this summation.

> Problem
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^n i \cdot 2^{i-1} = \ldots$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Look this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982265/how-to-solve-summation-by-hand?rq=1) answer by Martin Cohen might be helpful.

Comment: Have you heard the term Arithmetic-Geometric Progression/AGP? If not, [read this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-geometric-progression/)

Comment: BTW you could find a few similar questions simply by putting your sum [into Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5En%20i%20%5Ccdot%202%5E%7Bi-1%7D%24&p=1). In this case - since it is a question which (with some minor variations) is asked very often - looking in the [frequently asked question in the summation tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation?sort=frequent) would be a reasonable thing to do, too.

Comment: Here are two more similar questions: [How to compute the  formula $\sum  \limits_{r=1}^d r \cdot 2^r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11464) and [What is the sum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ip^i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180198)

Answer (score 1):

Using a geometric series we define a polynomial by $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^nx^i=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$ is the sum of the first n terms of a geometric progression. This is a standard result about geometric progression - if you are unfamiliar I believe others have added notes to guide you.

Now, our function $f$ is indeed differentiable as it is a finite polynomial.

So $$\begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^nix^{i-1}&=\frac d{dx}\left(\sum^n_{i=0}x^i\right)
\\&=\frac d{dx}\left(\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\right)
\end{align*}$$

paying close attention to the sum index.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: What I get is this,

$\sum_{i=1}^n ix^{i-1} = \dfrac{nx^{n-1} (x - 1) - x^n + 1}{(x-1)^2} $.

Then, I substitute $x = 2$, and I get

$n\cdot 2^{n-1} - 2^n + 1$. 

What is wrong with my work?

Comment: @MuhamadAbdulRosid I think you are close to the answer - check your differentiation. Or it's possible you are correct - I'm afraid I cannot check right now but later

Answer (score 1):

Let $S= \sum_{i=1}^{n} i.2^{i-1} = 1(1) + 2(2) + 3(4) + 4(8) + ... + n(2^{n-1}) $
$\quad\qquad\qquad 2S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i.2^{i} = 1(2) + 2(4) + 3(8) + ... + (n-1)(2^{n-1}) + n(2^n)$

Therefore, $2S-S = -(1+2+4+8+... + 2^{n-1}) + n(2^n) = - (2^n-1) + n(2^n)=2^n(n-1) +1$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\times x^{i-1} = (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^{i})' = (\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1})' = \frac{\big((n+1)x^{n} - 1\big)(x-1) - (x^{n+1}-x)}{(x-1)^{2}} $

Let $x=2$. Then, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\times 2^{i-1} = \big((n+1)2^{n} - 1\big) - (2^{n+1}-2)$